# Ho to view HTML from outside the xcode project

Tags: html, swift, xcode, macos, webview

I want to be able to load an HTML file located outside my app bundle, at the moment I can load the file by doing this:
This app is for MacOS

```
    let htmlPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "/html/index", ofType:"html")

    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: htmlPath!)

    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    webView.load(request)
```

This is loading the HTML file named index from my project resources. I want it to read the file from a user defined location. so the user could tell the app that the HTML file is on their desktop

my guess is that the code would be something like the following:

```
  @IBOutlet var fileLocation: NSTextField
  @IBOutlet var webView: WKWebView!

  var file = fileLocation.StringValue

  let htmlPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "\(file)", ofType:"html")

  let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: htmlPath!)

  let request = URLRequest(url: url)
  webView.load(request)
```

However, this above code results in a crash with the error

```
Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Is the error to do with saying the path is in Bundle.main.path?
If so what would I change that too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in the following line of code:

```
let htmlPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "\(file)", ofType:"html")
```

You are searching for the file in your app's application bundle when the file is in a user-defined location. The app can't find the file in the application bundle so `htmlPath` is nil. When you set the URL, the app crashes because you're implicitly unwrapping the nil `htmlPath`.

I can't tell you specifically what to change the path to because the path is user-defined. To solve your problem you need to keep track of the user-defined location in your app so you can load the file from there. User Defaults is a good place to save the user-defined location as part of the app's preferences. Look at the `UserDefaults` class in Apple's documentation. Look at the `FileManager` and `URL` classes to locate the file on the user's desktop and load it.